# Django validation

Tags: python, django, validation, model, boolean

I come from a Ruby on Rails background and I just started this project in Django.

I started messing with models and I just found out that for compatibility issues, Django doesn't full_clean (validate) a model instance before saving. Ok, weird.

The second surprise is the following:

- I create a model with a field `test` of type BooleanField (which default validation, by Django documentation, should be neither blank or null)
- I create a new instance of the above model without setting the field `test`
- I perform a full_clean and it returns `None`, all seems to be valid. Why?
- I perform a save and it returns `IntegrityError: null value in column "test" violates not-null constraint`.

Is it me or all this is just counterintuitive? How can I require and validate a field of type BooleanField?

EDIT:
I don't want to manage form submission since I would like to manage all data flow using django_rest_framework.

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the solution to the problem. The problem actually exists but is not yet nicely documented anywhere:

http://notes.noumenal.es/2017/12/13/required-by-default.html

Alternatively, just create a RequiredBooleanField like so:

```
class RequiredBooleanField(models.BooleanField):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RequiredBooleanField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.blank = False
        if 'blank' in kwargs.keys():
            self.blank = kwargs['blank']
```

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you try using a [ModelSerializer](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/serializers/#modelserializer) - it is the standard means to taking data submitted to your API, validating it, and creating an instance in your database.

Comment: I won't use forms to submit my data

Comment: @pnknrg I've updated my answer. I have used Django Rest Framework extensively, and ModelSerializers are what I believe you're looking for.

Comment: I am already using a serializer which by default gets the blank=True passed by the model definition. So that didn't do the trick either. I wrote the answer to my question below.